# How to focus on input field using react-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-select

I'm working on this dropdown using react-select and I have an **input field** inside of it that allows to do searches. Anyway, I have the following issues:

**1)** I should focus on the input field in **one click** (for some reason it requires 2 clicks)

**2)** When I open the dropdown and type a character it immediately loses focus (should not lose focus).

**3)** Let's say user types letter **"a"** inside the input field, then deletes it (now it's empty), now if users focus inside the input field again and hits **"backspace"** it closes the dropdown (this is wrong), the dropdown should stay open.

Could anyone tell me what am missing?
Thanks a lot in advance!!
Here's my [**LIVE DEMO**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-input-in-menulist-forked-nkllzx?file=/example.tsx)

**NOTE:**
I found a very similar example but can't seem to see what I'm missing or need to apply/change. Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish: [example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/m75wlyx3oy)

```
<Select
    classNamePrefix="select"
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    components={{
      DropdownIndicator,
      Group,
      GroupHeading,
      IndicatorSeparator,
      Input,
      MenuList: MenuListToRender,
      ValueContainer
    }}
    controlShouldRenderValue={false}
    hideSelectedOptions={false}
    isClearable={false}
    isMulti
    options={data}
    onKeyDown={(e) => console.log(e.key)}
    placeholder=""
    styles={customStyles}
    inputValue={inputValue}
    isSearchable={false}
    onMenuInputFocus={() => setIsFocused(true)}
    onChange={() => setIsFocused(false)}
    onInputChange={(val) => setInputValue(val)}
    {...{
      menuIsOpen: isFocused || undefined,
      isFocused: isFocused || undefined
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score -1):

onInputChange={(val) => setInputValue(val)}
hey bro i find error here

can  you please add this on OnChange={(val) => setInputValue(val)}

it will work.

Answer (score -1):

hi try to utilize the below component

```js
<Select
  // ...other props
  components={{
    // ...other components
    Menu: (props) => {
      const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
        if (e.key === 'Backspace') {
          e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default backspace behavior
        }
      };

      return (
        <components.Menu {...props} onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} />
      );
    },
  }}
  // ...
/>
```

Comment: This doesn’t not fix the focus issue and it blocks from deleting text

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).